# How to keep lambda parameter in memory?

Tags: c++, lambda

I currently have this test case:

```
std::function<void(void)> getFunc(int n) {
  return [&]() { std::cout << "N: " << n << std::endl; };
}

int main() {
  auto func = getFunc(3);
  func();
  return 0;
}
```

From an initial reading, one would expect `N: 3` to be printed, but the problem is that once the function getter goes out of scope, so does the `n` variable, causing undefined behavior. (In my particular case I got the output `N: 32766`.) How do I get around this and actually inject the value of `n` into my lambda for later use?

Comment: Capture by value.

Comment: So, basically make a struct that encapsulates it?

Comment: No. Replace `return [&]() { ... }` with `return [=]() { ... }`.

Comment: @iHowell No, replace `[&]` by `[n]` (or `[=]`). You should familiarize yourself with the different capturing options of lambdas because lifetime of captured variables is a huge issue (as you saw).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture